# Pug include unbuffered javascript

Tags: pug

Is there a way to include unbuffered javascript so multiple files can reuse the same functions, variables, etc.?

**Example**

```
- const viewbox = { x: 5000, y: 5000 };
```

Now I want to reuse this code across multiple files. Any ways to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work-around:**

This is possible in a rather unclean way: Create an pug file `empty.pug` (holding nothing, or a comment explaining why there is an empty file lying around that directory; if the empty strategy does not work, you can add a stub mixin in `empty.pug` just to please the compiler). Include that `empty` template in the pug template where you want to hold your JS code source, like this:

```
include empty

- function foo() { return "bar"; }
```

Now you can `include` that template in other templates that need the JS code.

*Old post:*

You can simply include the template file with that unbuffered JavaScript in any other Pug template file where you would like to use it. This can be done with the [`include`](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) keyword.

*Edit:*

It seems that this is only possible when you also include a mixin in the file holding the JavaScript. Work on a possibility to include pure JS code is on its way (according to [these](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/pull/1397) [two](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2550) GitHub issues on the Pug repo).

Comment: Even without any content, only the unbuffered javascript?

Comment: Yes, as long as you include it before you use it, the include also transfers any unbuffered JS to the parent template so that you can use it there just like in the included template

Comment: I include a file with only unbuffered javascript, but it when I try to log the variable, it comes out as undefined. Any ideas? It only has a `const` declaration in it.

Comment: How are you trying to log it? Not with `console.log` hopefully, since that is not available in this context, as far as I know...
But I just tried in one of my projects, and when I declare a variable in one template (`- const variableName = "test"`) and then include that in another template, I can render it without problems, e.g. through `p= variableName`.

Comment: Could there be an issue of using the pug-loader with webpack?

Comment: Have you done what is said in [this section](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader#includes) of the `pug-loader` readme?

Comment: Yes, my webpack is configured correctly. It only seems to compile correctly when there is a mixin in the file.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see what you mean, I get that error with `gulp-pug`, too, when I have no mixins in the file with the JS code (my fault, I had always tried it out in included files that already had mixins). Seems like the pug devs are working on a feature like this, according to the later comments on [this issue report](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2550).

Comment: Could you maybe share some code on how you got it to work? Maybe I can find a way to trick the compiler and include the unbuffered Javascript and not output anything.

Comment: How I now solved this is that I put a pug file called "_empty.pug" in my folder containing a mixin called "generate-empty-comment". Then I call the mixin from the file containing the JS code and then it works. Including it wasn't enough, but I marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Template Inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) and have a main template file (let's say `body.pug`) in which call say `block content` and a separate pug file for each page in which you `extends ./body` and define `block content` then the unbuffered code you put in `body.pug` will be available in every child pug file.

For example if you put the following in `body.pug`:

```
- let goat = true
```

You will be able to use that in any child pug file:

```
nav
  a( href='/') Home
  a( href='/blog) Blog
  if goat
     a( href='/goat') Goat
```